# The order of the time-space components of the metric tensor in post-Newtonian expansion

Tags: general-relativity, gauge, post-newtonian

In the book *Gravitational waves Vol.1: theory and experiment* by M.Maggiore, in chapter 5, page 239, the author announces that when we expand the metric tensor by $v \over c$, the components $g_{0i}$ start from order $({v \over c})^3$. But why? Why does the order $({v \over c})^1$ vanish?

I have a thought that this can be guessed from something like the Schwarz solution, where $g_{00}$ and $g_{ij}$ has order $({v \over c})^2$ (the $GM \over r$) while $g_{0i}$ is simply $0$. But in Schwarz solution this is because we did some gauge transformations. So, now in the post-Newtonian expansion, if we first have non-zero $g_{0i} ^{(1)}$ (the $({v \over c})^1$ order of $g_{0i}$), is it also possible that we do a gauge transformation so $g_{0i} ^{(1)}$ become $0$ ? If not, why can we assume $g_{0i} ^{(1)}$ to be simply $0$ ?